# What blog editor software are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, blog

I´m searching for a good blog editor like Windows Live Writer something similar.

Comment: This question is older. If you want to earn more reputation find other way!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.scribefire.com/ - Extension for FireFox and Chrome

Comment: As far as I can tell, ScribeFire is no more. It certainly seemed 404 when I checked.

Answer (score 6):

Blogilo isn't that bad, you should give it a try.

Comment: from the site "Bilbo is moving into KDE project" i prefer something for gnome.

Answer (score 5):

You could try BloGTK or Drivel (both should be in software center).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **[Blogilo](http://blogilo.gnufolks.org)**. You can install it via apt-get by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and typing `sudo apt-get install blogilo`, or you can **[download it manually](http://blogilo.gnufolks.org/download/)**

Comment: Blogilo is only for KDE or I'can use it in gnome to?

Comment: You can, just download it via sudo...