# An alternative software to Live Writer?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, blog

I want a software for blogging like Live Writer in Linux and GNOME.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: A similar question

http://askubuntu.com/questions/11317/blog-editor-software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Blogilo**](http://blogilo.gnufolks.org) is a great one.

[image]
[image]

---

**Edit**

[**ScribeFire Blog Editor**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scribefire-blog-editor/) is also a firefox (and some other browsers) extension which provides many features.

> ScribeFire is an extension for the Mozilla Firefox Web browser, Google Chrome Web browser, Opera Web Browser, and Apple Safari Web browser that allows you to easily post to all of your blogs.

[image]

---

**[Drivel](http://drivel.sourceforge.net/)** is another option:

> Drivel is a GNOME client for working with online journals, also known as weblogs or simply "blogs". It retains a simple and elegant design while providing many powerful features

[image]

and BloGTK also which is mentioned in previous answers.

Comment: I'd go with Blogilo, though I do on occasion use scribefire.

Answer (score 3):

For Markdown and other light-weight/readable markup languages there is the ReText editor.

Ubuntu users (10.04 and higher) can install ReText via `ppa:mitya57`.

Review: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/retext-text-editor-that-supports.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Wordpress there is Lekhonee, but not yet too feature-rich: https://fedorahosted.org/lekhonee/

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking of desktop clients then there is `blogilo` and `blogtk`. There is [one](http://www.getdeb.net/software/Opentumblr) for just Tumblr in [getdeb](http://getdeb.net).

Answer (score 1):

## [BloGTK](http://blogtk.jayreding.com/) ([Click To Install](http://apt.marcoceppi.com/p/blogtk) )

[image]

> BloGTK is a weblog client that allows you to post to your weblog from GNOME without the need for a separate browser window. BloGTK allows you to connect with many weblog systems such as Blogger, Movable Type, WordPress, and more. BloGTK is written using Python and PyGTK, and is designed to be fast and simple to use.
>
> BloGTK is open-source software released under the BSD license, which means that it is completely free for use.
>
> BloGTK won’t make you more attractive to the opposite sex, it won’t create world peace, and it doesn’t make julienne fries. It does make updating your weblog from Linux much easier and more efficient. On the other hand, that could make you more attractive to the opposite sex. (Guarantee of attractiveness void in this dimension.)